# Flag modal shows incorrect selection

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, flag-dialog, flag-reasons

I am aware that when we try to report a post, it cannot be done twice. But starting last week, I am experiencing this crazy thing. It shows I raised two types of report for the same post. Kindly have a look at the preview:

[image]

It shows both `Spam` as well as `Rude or Abusive`. Is it the intended behaviour or a bug? Let me know if I need to take down the question too. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug. As you can see, the message says:

> you have already raised this **type** of flag

See the word in bold - type. One type can  consist of many different items. So spam and offensive flags are of the same type.

This doesn't really matter though, since you [can't raise any other flag anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251296/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-you-have-already-raised-this-type-of-flag-message).